# ¿Por qué "mosca" es "bienes de cualquier especie" y "moneda corriente"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, significado

Las distintas acepciones de [**mosca**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pt3ozF8)

> 1. f. Insecto díptero muy común, de unos seis milímetros de largo, de cuerpo negro, cabeza elíptica, más ancha que larga, ojos salientes, alas transparentes cruzadas de nervios, patas largas con uñas y ventosas, y boca en forma de trompa, con la cual chupa las sustancias de que se alimenta.
> 2. f. Pelo que nace al hombre entre el labio inferior y el comienzo de la barba, y que algunos dejan crecer aun no llevando perilla.
> 3. f. Pequeña mancha negra o muy oscura.
> 4. f. **Bienes de cualquier especie.**
> 5. f. mosca artificial.
> 6. f. coloq. **Moneda corriente.**
> 7. f. coloq. Persona molesta, impertinente y pesada.
> 8. f. coloq. Desazón picante que inquieta y molesta. *Andrés está con mosca.*
> 9. f. Zool. Cada uno de los insectos dípteros del suborden de los braquíceros.
> 10. f. pl. coloq. Chispas que saltan de la lumbre.

se entienden bien por similitud en forma o comportamiento, literal o figuradamente, al del insecto de la primera acepción.

Para la acepción 2, véase por ejemplo el apartado 3 de http://abuelasabia.net/11-tipos-de-vello-facial-que-ningun-hombre-deberia-llevar/

Sin embargo, la acepción 4 **"Bienes de cualquier especie"** y 6 **"Moneda corriente"**, no parecen guardar ninguna relación con ninguna de las restantes. ¿Cómo se adquirieron esos significados?

Answer (score 5):

En el lenguaje del hampa, **coger la mosca** significaba "robar", haciendo alusión al movimiento que se hace para atrapar una mosca en vuelo. Y siguiendo el juego de palabras, la frase **aflojar la mosca** significaba "pagar", o sea, soltar las monedas que se habían robado. (Este uso es muy antiguo, ya aparece en *El Buscón* de Francisco Quevedo a principios del siglo XVII).

Supongo que de la germanía pasó al lenguaje corriente, perdiéndose gradualmente la imagen de la mosca en vuelo y el sentido de "botín". Con sentido del humor, las moscas pasaron a ser *dinero*, *monedas* o *bienes* no necesariamente robados.

Comment: _"Mas dicha tienen los picaros, que se les tolera, y aun aplaude en su Idioma xacarando, que llamen trena á la carcel, Xaque al valiente, Coillon al pregonero, gurapas á las galeras, mosca al dinero, trongas á las rameras, y finibus terrae á la horca, y otra inmensidad de terminos disparatados que merecieron tener quien los quisiera entender [...]"_ (Juan de Espinosa Medrano, "Apologético en favor de don Luis de Góngora", Perú, 1662.)

Comment: _"¿Qué príncipe, qué rey ni qué monarca / Puede tener, por mucho que le sobre, / Cuanta riqueza en todo el mundo abarca / De todos mis vasallos el más pobre? / Si es porque a los tales en el arca / Les sobra la moneda, plata o cobre, / Mayor de mis vasallos es la fama, / Pues el dinero ya mosca se llama."_ (José de Villaviciosa, "La Mosquea, Poética inventiva en octava rima", España, 1615.)

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de Rodrigo es correcta, sin embargo quisiera añadir un par de detalles sobre el uso común de la palabra:

Donde yo vivo, en Barcelona, jamás he oído a nadie usar la palabra "mosca" refiriéndose a nada que no sea la 1ª acepción, es decir, refiriéndose al insecto. El único otro uso del que puedo pensar (y que se deriva del insecto también) es decir que alguien *está mosqueado*, lo cual indica que está enfadado. Algunos ejemplos de su uso:

*El profesor de matemáticas está muy mosqueado con su clase.*

*El jefe anda mosqueado contigo.*

Comment: Para la acepción 2 ("Pelo que nace al hombre entre el labio inferior y el comienzo de la barba..."), ver el apartado 3 de http://abuelasabia.net/11-tipos-de-vello-facial-que-ningun-hombre-deberia-llevar/

Comment: Tampoco en México, mosca es un insecto.

Comment: En el habla de Buenos Aires, Argentina, era bastante común decir _mosca_ por "dinero", aunque creo que ya no es tan usual. También solía usarse la expresión _tener la mosca loca_ para decir que alguien tenía mucho dinero.